# R CMD check / devtools::test() and the current working directory

Tags: r, unit-testing, devtools

I am working on a R [package](https://github.com/almartin82/projprep) that has some functions that I want to test (locally) on data that I can't distribute, because the data source is proprietary.

I have a folder (`paid_projections`) where I'm keeping those files.  This caused some initial difficulties when running `devtools::test()` and R CMD check, I think because of subtle differences in the working directory that those utilities seen.

I've solved this problem by having my [tests](https://github.com/almartin82/projprep/blob/223857f11458b646ca64c4661004e5d8c97857a0/tests/testthat/test_pod.R) make some ad-hoc fixes to the path:

```
spec_file <- file.path('paid_projections', 'pod_projections.xlsx')
file_loc <- file.path(getwd(), spec_file)
#for CMD check
file_loc <- gsub('.Rcheck', '', file_loc, fixed = TRUE)
#for devtools::test()
file_loc <- gsub('tests/testthat/', '', file_loc, fixed = TRUE)
ex <- read_raw_pod(file_loc)
```

This... is less than ideal, and kind of makes me want to go take a shower.  It does create the behavior that I want (I can run these tests in the console, via `devtools::test()`, or R CMD check), but it doesn't feel like the correct solution.

There's a `devtools::wd()` command that seems like it might be helpful here, but I couldn't quite make sense of how that might replace the eyesore above.  Would love any suggestions!

Comment: Does `R CMD check` really work? I assume you don't put these files into your package (.tar.gz) that's why it could not really work. At least not on CRAN.

Comment: Good q, I'm not planning on submitting it to CRAN in the near-term, just using CMD check for code health / test-driven-development practices.  The RStudio/devtools/local version of it works.  Wouldn't work on CRAN, though.

Comment: At least for `devtools` you could do the following: put the data into `inst/paid` and add `inst/paid` to `.Rbuildignore` and `.gitignore`. Then you could use `system.file("paid", package="mypackage")` (it is overwritten by `devtools`) to get the correct path in the tests. I don't think this will work for `R CMD check` because `.Rbuildignore` prevent R from putting the data into the `tar.gz`.