# devtools::test() works but devtools::check() doesn't. Why?

Tags: r, unit-testing, travis-ci, devtools

I'm testing [this](https://github.com/beanumber/etl) R package.

The following three things work just fine:

- `devtools::test()`
- `devtools::test_file("tests/testthat.R")`
- [Travis-CI with release version of R](https://travis-ci.org/beanumber/etl/jobs/277934695)

However, the following things

- `devtools::check()`
- `devtools::build_win()` # (see win-builder output [here](https://win-builder.r-project.org/5X9Wv481469s/00check.log))

produce this error:

> R CMD check results 1 error  | 0 warnings | 0 notes checking tests ...
>   ERROR   Running ‘testthat.R’ Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’
>   failed. Last 13 lines of output:   40: mutate_.data.frame(., city_pop
>   = ~readr::parse_number(Population..4), metro_pop = ~readr::parse_number(Population..5), 
>            urban_pop = ~readr::parse_number(Population..6), Country = ~gsub(",", "_", Country))   41: mutate(.data, !(!(!dots)))   42:
>   mutate.data.frame(.data, !(!(!dots)))   43:
>   as.data.frame(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))   44: mutate(tbl_df(.data),
>   ...)   45: mutate.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), ...)   46: mutate_impl(.data,
>   dots)
>        testthat results ================================================================   OK: 34 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 1
>     1. Error: cities works (@test-etl.R#113) 
>        Error: testthat unit tests failed   Execution halted

Additionally, the [old release Travis-CI job](https://travis-ci.org/beanumber/etl/jobs/277934693) throws an error about `dplyr` and `readr` being missing, and the [development release Travis-CI job](https://travis-ci.org/beanumber/etl/jobs/277934696) throws an error about not being able to connect to the database. (I sort of suspect that these errors are unrelated to the above.)

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846465/testthat-fails-within-devtoolscheck-but-works-in-devtoolstest) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272119/r-cmd-check-fails-devtoolstest-works-fine) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674798/r-devtools-test-errors-but-testthat-test-file-works) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973359/r-cmd-check-devtoolstest-and-the-current-working-directory) but none of these seem to be my problem.

I've tried all of my usual tricks and I'm fairly confident that there is not actually a bug in the code, there is just some kind of environment/`NAMESPACE` mismatch that I don't understand and don't know how to debug.

Any ideas? I'm on `Ubuntu` using `R 3.4.1`.

**MWE**

```
# shell
git clone git@github.com:beanumber/etl.git
# R
library(devtools)
test()
check()
```

Comment: I actually solved my own problem (I was using `test_check()` with the wrong package name -- long story!) but would still be happy to see good answers to this question.  I've had a number of issues in the past with apparent weirdness in the `check()` and `test()` environments relative to simply `source()`ing the relevant file ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer (and the one I always use, especially when writing code for others or "self-use" packages) is to use the convention package_name::function() when you use functions imported from other packages.

E.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)


df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)))
df %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise(mean_value = mean(a), count = n())
```

isn't going to work. dplyr::summarise() will
(doing it this way actually throws a very useful warning).

Overall, everytime you load a library you will get a statement saying which functions from the package are already defined elsewhere. E.g. for dplyr on my laptop: 
    The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

If you look at those warnings you can see which functions you can't / shouldn't call anymore. Note that the in the above case the base function "union" can now only be called by base::union, a standard call of union() will use the dplyr function. In other words, the most recently loaded library is the one used by "default".

Hope that helped